# updating edmx for EF6 always seems to miss fields and doesnt update the Create call

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

using VS 2015, I am updating an application using an existing EF6 edmx (updating a table that has a new field CostPerTruck)

The following partial class gets updated:

```
public partial class StateAttributeLookup : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new StateAttributeLookup object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state">Initial value of the State property.</param>
    /// <param name="region">Initial value of the Region property.</param>
    /// <param name="pricebookID">Initial value of the PricebookID property.</param>
    /// <param name="fuelSurcharge">Initial value of the FuelSurcharge property.</param>
    /// <param name="rPMOMNI0613">Initial value of the RPMOMNI0613 property.</param>
    /// <param name="stateMinimum">Initial value of the StateMinimum property.</param>
    /// <param name="notes">Initial value of the Notes property.</param>
    /// <param name="createDateTime">Initial value of the CreateDateTime property.</param>
    /// <param name="createUser">Initial value of the CreateUser property.</param>
    /// <param name="modifyDateTime">Initial value of the ModifyDateTime property.</param>
    /// <param name="modifyUser">Initial value of the ModifyUser property.</param>
    /// <param name="distanceToState">Initial value of the DistanceToState property.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceApplication">Initial value of the SourceApplication property.</param>
    /// <param name="costPerTruck">Initial value of the CostPerTruck property.</param>
    public static StateAttributeLookup CreateStateAttributeLookup(global::System.String state, global::System.String region, global::System.Guid pricebookID, global::System.Double fuelSurcharge, global::System.Double rPMOMNI0613, global::System.Double stateMinimum, global::System.String notes, global::System.DateTime createDateTime, global::System.String createUser, global::System.DateTime modifyDateTime, global::System.String modifyUser, global::System.Int32 distanceToState, global::System.String sourceApplication, global::System.Double costPerTruck)
    {
        StateAttributeLookup stateAttributeLookup = new StateAttributeLookup();
        stateAttributeLookup.State = state;
        stateAttributeLookup.Region = region;
        stateAttributeLookup.PricebookID = pricebookID;
        stateAttributeLookup.FuelSurcharge = fuelSurcharge;
        stateAttributeLookup.RPMOMNI0613 = rPMOMNI0613;
        stateAttributeLookup.StateMinimum = stateMinimum;
        stateAttributeLookup.Notes = notes;
        stateAttributeLookup.CreateDateTime = createDateTime;
        stateAttributeLookup.CreateUser = createUser;
        stateAttributeLookup.ModifyDateTime = modifyDateTime;
        stateAttributeLookup.ModifyUser = modifyUser;
        stateAttributeLookup.DistanceToState = distanceToState;
        stateAttributeLookup.SourceApplication = sourceApplication;
        stateAttributeLookup.CostPerTruck = costPerTruck;
        return stateAttributeLookup;
    }
```

However the StateAttributeLookup class does not and the CreateStateAttributeLookup method called in the BeginEdit method is missing the argument for the new field CostPerTruck. Both the BeginEdit and CancelEdit methods are missing the new field.

```
public partial class StateAttributeLookup : IEditableObject
{
    private StateAttributeLookup _backupCopy;
    private bool _inEdit;

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        if (!_inEdit)
        {
            _inEdit = true;
            _backupCopy = StateAttributeLookup.CreateStateAttributeLookup(this.State, this.Region, this.PricebookID, this.FuelSurcharge, this.RPMOMNI0613, this.StateMinimum, this.Notes, this.CreateDateTime, this.CreateUser, this.ModifyDateTime, this.ModifyUser, this.DistanceToState, this.SourceApplication);
        }
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        if (_inEdit)
        {
            _inEdit = false;
            this.State = _backupCopy.State;
            this.Region = _backupCopy.Region;
            this.PricebookID = _backupCopy.PricebookID;
            this.FuelSurcharge = _backupCopy.FuelSurcharge;
            this.RPMOMNI0613 = _backupCopy.RPMOMNI0613;
            this.StateMinimum = _backupCopy.StateMinimum;
            this.Notes = _backupCopy.Notes;
            this.CreateDateTime = _backupCopy.CreateDateTime;
            this.CreateUser = _backupCopy.CreateUser;
            this.ModifyDateTime = _backupCopy.ModifyDateTime;
            this.ModifyUser = _backupCopy.ModifyUser;
        }
    }
```

So my question is becomes why?  Should I delete the entity (StateAttributeLookup) and then update the edmx?  I tried that and got the same results even after running the "Run Custom Tool" against the T4 template.

I have noticed this behavior from a fellow co-worker who basically scrapped the edmx and just built a new one.  I don't feel that this should be the case, that updating the model from the database should catch all the changes and handle the generations correctly.

Am I missing something, some step?  I would really appreciate finding a solution to this irritating problem because this app is now having schema changes and this is just the start of table mods.

thanks

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer, but I would highly suggest switching to the [Reverse Poco Generator][1] and ditching the Edmx altogether.

Edmx suffers from serious problems should you ever need to merge changes from different branches, and is not as customizable as this tool.


  [1]: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Comment: It seems, you wanted to keep some customized code even after you refresh with edmx generator?. EDMX regenerate entire context from scratch if any entity updated.

Comment: @Prathyush - this is not customized code.  This is code that EF generates via the T4.... for whatever reason it has issues and does not generate code correctly.

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr. ... that is almost looking like a more desirable way to go, however Im not sure how much time I am going to get allotted to get these new set of changes made.  I am going to have to do something to to be sure.  Thank you for the link :)

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the Edmx update process to update a partial class that isn't generated. That is never going to happen. If you need custom code added to your generated types, reverse poco is the way to go.

Comment: Adult programmers do not use edmx or Entity Framework in general, unless they need to create a pilot throw away.

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli ... maybe you should put the pipe down....